Lightweight self-hosted VoIP server
I am looking for a self-hosted and minimalist VoIP chat system. It will run locally on my computer and will listen on a TCP port for incoming VoIP connections. It only needs one-on-one chat abilities, and the remote side should access it via HTTP in their browser and must not be required to download some app.
Requirements

Very lightweight, ideally CLI
Serves the client over HTTP for browsers (e.g. on LAN, dynamic DNS etc)
Supports TCP and can handle high latencies
Uses Opus for audio
Encryption and authentication is not necessary

One reason I want it to be minimalist is so that I can hack in changes if necessary (like making Opus CBR if it is not already). If nothing like this exists then I could hack the server side together myself as long as there's a JS library out there for a minimalist VoIP client.
I've looked into Jitsi and Mumble (Murmur) and they are far too heavy for my purposes.

Is it OK if the service uses UDP? Because TCP is a bad choice for realtime communication.
